# the url is removing the root directory

Tags: php, .htaccess, ubuntu

i am working on php7 on ubuntu 17.10.
i have my url as : http://localhost/thedoctorincubator/
when i want to goto http://localhost/thedoctorincubator/admin it is redirecting to http://localhost/admin.
I am unable to find the reason.

my .htaccess file is :

Options -MultiViews

```
RewriteEngine On

# Redirect Trailing Slashes...
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with this code :

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]

Comment: replace your existing .htaccess code with this code hope this will help you

Comment: did that .. didn't help :(

Comment: remove your htaccess previous code completely and add this code its working fine on my system

Comment: verify that is there any other htaccess file is the in localhost root folder

Comment: i removed my code and pasted yours. but it didnt help. are u also on ubuntu ?

Comment: yes i'm using it , if you are using framework then please check with routs [